# how to handle nested arrays with a v-for

Tags: vue.js

assuming I have a dropdown that I need to populate with items, but they are dynamically generated based on the dropdown that was selected before it... so... like...using the examples of vehicles... lets say i have vehicle data like this.. 
vehicleDetails.json

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "make": "Subaru",
    "models": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Forrester",
            "years": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
            "series": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "SH",
                    "years": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "SJ",
                    "years": [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "SK",
                    "years": [2018, 2019, 2020]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Impreza",
            "years": [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
            "series": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "GJ",
                    "years": [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "GT",
                    "years": [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"2": {
    "id": 1,
    "make": "Toyota",
    "models": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Camry",
            "years": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
            "series": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "XV40",
                    "years": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "XV70",
                    "years": [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "4Runner",
            "years": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
            "series": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "N210",
                    "years": [2009]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "GT",
                    "years": [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I three inline drop downs that show make, model, and series. I need it to only show models that are related to makes, and series that are related to models. but these are nested arrays and a v-for only handles one array at a time. And the id's don't seem to be relevant to each other... like.. the id of 4runner is the same as Imprezza. Struggling here. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple divs with multiple v-for's to handle multiple levels of an array.

Or you can use a reducer: https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-reducer/

Or a filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

to extract out the appropriate "series" key then you can just iterate over the single level array.

Using Methods in vueJs will be the ideal way to format your data so your templating is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working component using your data as `carData`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="make">
      <option v-for="m in makes" :key="m.id" :value="m">{{ m.make }}</option>
    </select>
    <select v-model="model">
      <option v-for="m in models" :key="m.id" :value="m">{{ m.name }}</option>
    </select>
    <select v-model="year">
      <option v-for="y in years" :key="y" :value="y">{{ y }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const CAR_DATA = {
  '1': {
    id: 1,
    make: 'Subaru',
    models: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Forrester',
        years: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        series: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'SH',
            years: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'SJ',
            years: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'SK',
            years: [2018, 2019, 2020],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Impreza',
        years: [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        series: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'GJ',
            years: [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'GT',
            years: [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  '2': {
    id: 2,
    make: 'Toyota',
    models: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Camry',
        years: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        series: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'XV40',
            years: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'XV70',
            years: [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: '4Runner',
        years: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        series: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'N210',
            years: [2009],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'GT',
            years: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      make: null,
      model: null,
      year: null,
      carData: CAR_DATA,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    makes() {
      return Object.values(this.carData);
    },
    models() {
      return this.make ? this.make.models : [];
    },
    years() {
      return this.model ? this.model.years : [];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The nice thing about this implementation is that you don't actually have to traverse the object. The trick is entirely in choosing the right `value` object for each `option`.